# Is the Visual Studio 2012 RC Diff Utility Compare-Only?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I swear that in earlier versions of the preview/beta/whatever I was not only able to view the difference between two files, but also merge/update.  Now I'm looking at a diff window and as far as I can tell there is no way to move lines from left to right, or right to left.

[image: Screenshot of Diff UI]

The window has a "Help" link at the bottom, leading to this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfs/bb385990%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which, unfortunately has no coverage of any kind of merge.  The only way I can do it at the moment is to manually copy and paste, or type the text on the left into the pane on the right.

Did Microsoft remove these features opting for a "compare-only" diff utility?

Are these tools available somewhere I'm not looking?

Is it possible my installation is corrupted?  Can anyone confirm that they can not only compare, but also update using the RC.

Answer (score 5):

The compare tool (I believe) doesn't have any merge options. However, if you right-click on a file in source control explorer and go to Branching & Merging > Merge you can perform a baseless merge between any two files (you have to browse for the file), and resolve conflicts within the merge tool. Hope that helps.

Comment: After a little more work, I believe the answer may be in local workspaces. If I use a local copy of the two files to compare, I can make changes, but if either is a server copy I cannot. This may be more of the answer you were looking for. Which may make this more of a TFS 2012 question, than VS 2012.

Comment: No its a VS 2012 question.  If way to do merging requires TFS, then the answer to this specific question is, "No, the VS diff tool has no merge capability."  I appreciate your comments though, its more or less in line with what I've been able to determine so far on my own.  And I know this capability was available in the pre-UI Refresh versions of VS11.