# When we compare local version with server version in Visual Studio, how to make the local version editable?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I found that sometimes when I use "compare" in Visual Studio, I couldn't edit the local version at all. But sometimes it does allow this. Is there any setting in TFS that is related to this functionality?

The steps I followed:
Right clicked the file in Solution Explorer I want to compare, and chose "Compare", with the dialog window popped out like this:

[image]

and cliked "OK"

I found several questions similar to my question, but amazingly all of them don't have even a relevant answer:

[Visual Studio Diff Tool - When is Editing Allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046067/visual-studio-diff-tool-when-is-editing-allowed)

[Under what conditions will the Visual Studio 2012 Difference Viewer allowing editing a source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335052/under-what-conditions-will-the-visual-studio-2012-difference-viewer-allowing-edi?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Comment: Can you show how you're opening the compare dialog?  Are you comparing with your *local file* or are you comparing with *your workspace version*?  One is a local file, the other is a view of the file as it exists on the server at the version you retrieved locally.

Comment: @EdwardThomson I added the dialog, the target path is a local path, so it should be the local file, correct? :

Comment: Yes, that's true.  Are you using a server workspace or a local workspace?

Comment: I'm using local workspace

Comment: Finally I found in my project's scenario, only javascript file can be edited, *.cshtml and *.cs file couldn't not be edited.